# Редирект с Меты ХК

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Сегодня с удивлением обнаружил, что [Мета ХэшКода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) не только жива, но и шлёт мне дайджест интересных вопросов:

[image]

Редирект с Меты ХК на Мету ru.SO отсутствует. Кто-то даже умудряется постить туда вопросы. Так и задумано или просто забыли перенаправить? И что стало с остальными сайтами "Сети Знаний"? Они тоже переехали на движок SO? По крайней мере, ссылка "сеть знаний" в заголовке старой Меты ведёт на ru.SO.

Comment: А я на старую мету даже залогиниться не могу. У меня аккаунт привязан к гуглу, а гугл уже выпилил старый способ авторизации, как выяснилось. И отписаться я тоже не могу, потому что отписка требует авторизации. И что мне теперь с рассылкой делать?

Comment: Призываю в тред @Nicolas Chabanovsky. На старой Мете постят [спам](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/4346/) и [вопросы на SO](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/4345/), а Мета шлёт всё это добро мне (и, видимо, другим подписавшимся) на почту в виде еженедельной рассылки. Войти и отписаться я не могу. Добавить фильтр и отправлять письма прямиком в спам - могу, но хотелось бы более радикального решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенастроил старый сервер: теперь уведомления о вопросах на старой Мете отправляться больше не будут.

В дополнение перенес все вопросы, которые на мой взгляд следовало перенести. Справку по редактированию перевода добавил на саму страницу [Справочного Центра](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Спасибо! А долго старая Мета ещё будет жива? Без присмотра там уже завелись спамеры, не лучше ли будет окончательно закрыть её, если нет ресурсов на модерацию?

Comment: Я планирую остановить ее в ближайшее время, так как в любом случае дамп базы будет доступен. После остановки добавим перенаправление на новую Мету.